# javascript can't pass string to my function

Tags: javascript

I was calling my function with parameter date string like "24/08/2017" and my function is

```
function openEdit(dateid){
    alert(dateid);
    }
```

And it's return 0.00013882002974714924. The function call is like

```
<button onclick="openEdit(datestring)"></button>
```

Comment: Can I see your whole HTML code? Where can you get datestring?

Comment: Well, `24/08/2017` evaluates to `0.00013882002974714924`, right?

Comment: how you gets `datestring` ?

Comment: I get datastring using php echo.

Comment: <button onclick="openEdit(<?php echo $datasring; ?>)"></button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this if you are using a server side technology

```
<button onclick="openEdit(\''+datestring+'\')"></button>
```

or

```
<button onclick="openEdit('<yourdate>')"></button>
```

You just need to add some quotes around the datestring

Comment: That's a syntax error without more context (like, for instance, what server-side thing they're using to produce the result).

Comment: you can use this or add quotes just around quotes  @T.J.Crowder. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be putting the date in with no delimiters:

```
<button onclick="openEdit(24/08/2017)"></button>
```

That does the math `24/08/2017` and passes the *result*, `0.001487357461576599`, into the function.

Put quotes around it:

```
<button onclick="openEdit('24/08/2017')"></button>
```

You're probably doing this with a server-side technology, perhaps PHP. If it's PHP, then presumably you're using `echo` or similar:

```
echo '<button onclick="openEdit(' . datestring . ')"></button>';
```

If so, just put the quotes on either side:

```
echo '<button onclick="openEdit(\'' . datestring . '\')"></button>';
```

Comment: Yes I was using php echo.

Comment: My code is like 
 
<button onclick="openEdit(<?php echo '\'.$datasring.'\' ; ?>)"></button>
?

Comment: @LinAung: That would actually output the characters `$datasring` (did you mean to have a `t` in that?). Instead, just put `'` next to the `(` and `)`: `<button onclick="openEdit('<?php echo $datasring ; ?>')"></button>`

Answer (score 0):

```
function openEdit(dateid){
  var temp = new Date(dateid);
  alert(temp);
}
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the date to a string it actually performs the `/` operation.You can convert to string by using `toString()` method in JS.